# Is Facebook SDK Documentation for Swift outdated? What is the corresponding SDK version?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am building an iOS app which requires sharing on Facebook. I am using Swift(4) on Xcode(9). So I started using the documentation from the official page of Facebook -> [Facebook Swift SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/sharing/content-types)
However, to my surprise almost every example listed in this page and others are giving compilation errors. For e.g. on this page there is a suggested way for `LinkShareContent` as per below:

```
import FacebookShare
let content = LinkShareContent(url: NSURL("https://developers.facebook.com"))
try ShareDialog.show(from: myViewController, content: content)
```

But the minute I add this to my code, I get the error -> `Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads` on the `NSURL`

So it seems like the documentation for Facebook SDK for Swift is outdated. Am I correct? if yes, can someone please guide me to the most updated version? Or what are my other options?
If someone can at least tell me which version the current documentation corresponds to, then at least I can start working on an older version of the SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDK has been updated for Swift 4, but apparently not the documentation. The correct Swift 4 syntax for creating `NSURL` from a string requires a `string` argument label:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://developers.facebook.com")
```

You are looking at Facebook's official documentation, so I don't know where to point you to anything more up-to-date. It might help to re-type their example code into your project so you can get the right auto-completion suggestions from Xcode.

EDIT: In Swift, many classes with the `NS` prefix have been replaced by classes without the prefix. For example, `NSURL` has been replaced in favor of `URL`. Facebook has updated their `LinkShareContent` class to take a `URL` in the initializer:

```
public init(url: URL, quote: String? = nil)
```

So this should work:

```
let content = LinkShareContent(url: URL(string: "https://developers.facebook.com"))
```

P.S. Again, this is the reason you should re-type their example code instead of copy/pasting. As soon as you type `let content = LinkShareContent(`, Xcode will you show you that the initializer needs a `URL` not `NSURL`.

Comment: If I use your suggested construct, I get the following error in Xcode -> 'NSURL' is not implicitly convertible to 'URL'; did you mean to use 'as' to explicitly convert?

Comment: Basically, it is now a trial and error game till Facebook updates their documentation :-)